# React-Router Switch causing the current route to re-mount whenever redux state changes

Tags: redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router v4. However, whenever my applications Redux state is updated, React-Router's Switch component is updating and re-mounting the current route.

I define my HashRouter at in the main index.js file, like so:

```
/* global document */

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './screens/app/index'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

import './styles/main.css'

import store from './store'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
registerServiceWorker()
```

This is my component using the Switch component:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const propTypes = {
  routes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    path: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    container: PropTypes.object,
    exact: PropTypes.bool,
  })).isRequired,
}

const Router = ({ routes }) => (
  <Switch>
    <div className="container">
      {routes.map(route => (
        <Route
          key={route.path}
          path={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          component={() => route.container}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </Switch>
)

Router.propTypes = propTypes

export default Router
```

And finally, I setup my store here:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

import reducer from './reducers/index'

export default createStore(reducer)
```

I was thinking possible issues could be:

- There an issue with my Redux setup that is causing a collision with the redux store
- The Routes aren't defined correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is the line that remounts the component everytime

```
component={() => route.container}
```

try

```
const Router = ({ routes }) => (
  <Switch>
   <div className="container">
     {routes.map(route => {
       const routerComp = () => route.container 
       return (
         <Route
          key={route.path}
          path={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          component={routerComp}
        />
       )
     })}
</div>
```

)